# How can I use django template filter to delete the last character?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a string such as `100M`, I want to delete the `M`, how can I do that?

I tried use `slice` filter, but the number length is variable(maybe `1000` or others), so, how can I do that?

---

**EDIT**

the string maybe `""` (empty string), so can not use the `splice:"-1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ var|slice:"-1" }}
```

you can use negative number for slice filter

Comment: What do you want to do when it's `M`?

Comment: if it's `""`,no exception raise,`{{ var|slice:"-1" }} ` still useful